# Exercise $P(E_1>E_2)=$?

Tags: probability

Good Day,

If we have a probability space $(\Sigma,A,P)$ and two independent random variables $ E_1 ,E_2$ which follow the exponential distribution with $1$ as a parameter.

What is the probability of $P(E_1>E_2)$ ?
I don't understand, in the correction, how they can say that $P(E_1=E_2)=0$
.

Indeed, they say :
As the probability law of $(E_1,E_2)$ is the same as the one for $(E_2,E_1)$ and that $P(E_1=E_2)=0$, we have that $$1=P(E_1>E_2)+P(E_1=E_2)+P(E_2>E_1)=2P(E_1>E_2)$$ Thus, $P(E_1>E_2)=\frac{1}{2}$.

I am not pretty sure to understand really how the sentence "the probability law of $(E_1,E_2)$ is the same as the one for $(E_2,E_1)$" is true.

With all my respect,

Comment: $E_1,E_2$ are two identically distributed variables, so interchanging them has no effect on probabilities.

Comment: In general, $\mathbb P(E_1=E_2)=0$ for independent continuous random variables. The result that $\mathbb P(E_1>E_2)=\frac12$ for i.i.d. $E_1,E_n$ follows from symmetry, as does the more general result $\mathbb P(E_1 =\max_{i\leqslant 1\leqslant n} E_i)=\frac1n$ for i.i.d. $E_1,\ldots,E_n$.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I think I now understand why $P(E_1=E_2)=0$ with your help. May I ask :  for " the probability law of (E1,E2) is the same as the one for (E2,E1) ", do we use the independance ? Indeed, for all $F_1,F_2 \in A$, $P_{(E_1,E_2)}(F_1 \times F_2)=P(\{E_1 \in F_1 \} \cap \{E_2 \in F_2\})=P( E_1 \in F_1)P(E_2 \in F_2)=P(\{E_2 \in F_2 \} \cap \{E_1 \in F_1\}) =P_{(E_2,E_1)}(F_2 \times F_1)$.

Comment: You need independence. For example if $E_1,E_2$ are the same variable $E,$ then they are certainly not independent, and also $P(E_1>E_2)=P(E>E)=0.$